# cryptdecrypt API not able to decrypt 3Des Encrypted data on Windows 11

Tags: java, c++, bouncycastle, msdn, windows-11

My application runs on Windows desktop. Algorithm used is Triple DES. The Data is encrypted on the server using Bouncycastle java API. The application is able to decrypt the data on Windows 10 but fails to decrypt correctly on windows 11. It decrypts the first part of the data correctly the remaining part is remains encrypted.

Java Encryption:

```
    static final int BLOCK_SIZE_3DES = 8;
    public byte[] encryptDESede(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] initVec) throws StandardException {  
    //add paddingif req
    if(data.length % BLOCK_SIZE_3DES != 0) {     
     byte[] padding = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE_3DES - (data.length % BLOCK_SIZE_3DES)];     
     for (int i = 0; i < padding.length; i++) 
       padding[i] = (byte) padding.length;     
     data = Bytes.join(new byte[][]{data, padding});   
    }  
    
    
     BlockCipher engine = new DESedeEngine(); 
    CBCBlockCipher cbc = new CBCBlockCipher(engine);  
     BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(cbc);   cipher.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), initVec)); 
    byte[] out = new byte[data.length];   cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, out, 0);   
    return out;
    }
```

C++ Decryption

```
bool Decipher(CData & _Data) const {

    DWORD FinalSize = _Data.size();
    //check that size is multiple of 8
    if ( _Data.size() % 8) {
        return false;
    }
    
    BOOL Result = CryptDecrypt(m_Key, 0, TRUE, 0, _Data.data(), &FinalSize);
    
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (Result == FALSE && err != NTE_BAD_DATA)
        return false;

    if ((Result == FALSE) && (err == NTE_BAD_DATA)) {
        CData EmptyBlob;
        Encipher(EmptyBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return ciphered data and final size
        _Data.resize(FinalSize);
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I make it work on windows 11 as well? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: _It decrypts the first part of the data correctly_ - maybe `CryptDecrypt(m_Key, 0, TRUE` - should be [FALSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt#remarks)

Comment: Tried..but didn't work